# Problema con decimales en tkinter TableCanvas

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

El código baja archivos de una base de datos Mysql y los coloca en una hoja de cálculo de tkinter. el problema es que el resultado no sale completo y la terminal me arroja un error: **TypeError: object of type 'decimal.Decimal' has no len()** Varios de los valores en la tabla de tkinter son número decimales, alguien sabe cómo resolverlo?

```
Ventana_reporte_diario=customtkinter.CTk()
Ventana_reporte_diario.geometry("700x300")


Variable_fecha=customtkinter.StringVar(value='30/11/2022')
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor1.execute('''SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha='{0}' '''.format(Variable_fecha.get()))
resultado=cursor1.fetchall()
print(resultado)
conn.commit()
conn.close()



label_titulo=customtkinter.CTkLabel(Ventana_reporte_diario, text="Movimientos del día", text_font=("arial", 18))
label_titulo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

def visualizar():
    ventana_2=customtkinter.CTkToplevel()
    ventana_2.geometry("1000x600")
    
    df_sql_data= pd.DataFrame(resultado)
    df_sql_data.columns=[str(col) for col in df_sql_data.columns]
    for column in ('6', '14', '15', '16', '17'):
        df_sql_data[column] = df_sql_data[column].astype(float)
    
    tframe = Frame(ventana_2)
    tframe.pack(pady=5, padx=5, fill=BOTH)
    table = TableCanvas(tframe, read_only=True,  cellbackgr='#FFFFFF', data=df_sql_data.to_dict("index"))
    table.show()

def exportar_a_excell():
    x_df=pd.DataFrame(resultado)
    file = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx")
    x_df.to_excel(str(file)+'.xlsx', index=False)

boton_visualizar=customtkinter.CTkButton(Ventana_reporte_diario, text="Visualizar", command=visualizar)
boton_visualizar.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)

boton_excell=customtkinter.CTkButton(Ventana_reporte_diario, text="Exportar a excell", command=exportar_a_excell)
boton_excell.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)


Ventana_reporte_diario.mainloop()
```

Agrego el output de la terminal cuando le imprimo la lista df_sql_data, creo que el problema es que suma demasiados ceros a los decimales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera recalcar, que cuando veo en la base de datos, los números solo tienen un decimal

EDIT: Escribí una versión simplificada del programa, y agregué la modificación sugerida en la respuesta, pero creo que lo hice mal ya que el problema persiste. Aquí dejo el código:

```
Ventana_reporte_diario=customtkinter.CTk()
Ventana_reporte_diario.geometry("700x300")


        Variable_fecha=customtkinter.StringVar(value='30/11/2022')
        conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
        cursor1=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cursor1.execute('''SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha='{0}' '''.format(Variable_fecha.get()))
        resultado=cursor1.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        
        
        
        label_titulo=customtkinter.CTkLabel(Ventana_reporte_diario, text="Movimientos del día", text_font=("arial", 18))
        label_titulo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        def visualizar():
            ventana_2=customtkinter.CTkToplevel()
            ventana_2.geometry("1000x600")
            
            df_sql_data= pd.DataFrame(resultado)
            df_sql_data.columns=[str(col) for col in df_sql_data.columns]
            for column in df_sql_data['6', '14', '15', '16', '17']:
                df_sql_data[column]=df_sql_data[column].astype(float)
            
            tframe = Frame(ventana_2)
            tframe.pack(pady=5, padx=5, fill=BOTH)
            table = TableCanvas(tframe, read_only=True,  cellbackgr='#FFFFFF', data=df_sql_data.to_dict("index"))
            table.show()
        
        boton_visualizar=customtkinter.CTkButton(Ventana_reporte_diario, text="Visualizar", command=visualizar)
        boton_visualizar.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        boton_excell=customtkinter.CTkButton(Ventana_reporte_diario, text="Exportar a excell")
        boton_excell.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    Ventana_reporte_diario.mainloop()
```

Usé corchetes porque al usar paréntesis la terminal me daba: **TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

EDIT: A petición de los que me están ayudando, agrego el output de la variable `print(resultado)` :

> [{'Numero': 1, 'Placa': '986NTW2', 'Conductor': 'Mario', 'Cedula':
> 25814334, 'Producto': 'maiz', 'Numero_guia': 5, 'Peso_guia':
> Decimal('50000.000'), 'Proveedor': 'Metalúrgia', 'Cliente': '',
> 'Despacho': '', 'Transporte': 'Balarca', 'Fecha': '30/11/2022',
> 'Hora': '12:38:41 PM', 'Observaciones': 'No', 'Peso_balanza':
> Decimal('50000.000'), 'Peso_tara': Decimal('46000.000'), 'Peso_neto':
> Decimal('4000.000'), 'Peso_diferencia': Decimal('0.000')}, {'Numero':
> 2, 'Placa': 'AA634SP', 'Conductor': 'Mario', 'Cedula': 25814334,
> 'Producto': 'Trigo', 'Numero_guia': 44, 'Peso_guia':
> Decimal('500000.000'), 'Proveedor': 'Metalúrgia', 'Cliente': '',
> 'Despacho': '', 'Transporte': 'Balarca', 'Fecha': '30/11/2022',
> 'Hora': '12:39:24 PM', 'Observaciones': 'No', 'Peso_balanza':
> Decimal('500000.000'), 'Peso_tara': Decimal('46000.000'), 'Peso_neto':
> Decimal('454000.000'), 'Peso_diferencia': Decimal('0.000')},
> {'Numero': 3, 'Placa': 'KAH86WX', 'Conductor': 'Mario', 'Cedula':
> 25814334, 'Producto': 'pollo', 'Numero_guia': 23, 'Peso_guia':
> Decimal('400000.000'), 'Proveedor': 'Milazo', 'Cliente': '',
> 'Despacho': '', 'Transporte': 'Balarca', 'Fecha': '30/11/2022',
> 'Hora': '12:40:17 PM', 'Observaciones': 'No', 'Peso_balanza':
> Decimal('400000.000'), 'Peso_tara': Decimal('17600.000'), 'Peso_neto':
> Decimal('382400.000'), 'Peso_diferencia': Decimal('0.000')},
> {'Numero': 4, 'Placa': 'A15332X', 'Conductor': 'Edgar', 'Cedula':
> 11725788, 'Producto': 'maiz', 'Numero_guia': 98, 'Peso_guia':
> Decimal('25000.000'), 'Proveedor': '', 'Cliente': 'El tunal',
> 'Despacho': 'Fábrica', 'Transporte': 'Balarca', 'Fecha': '30/11/2022',
> 'Hora': '12:41:24 PM', 'Observaciones': 'No', 'Peso_balanza':
> Decimal('25000.000'), 'Peso_tara': Decimal('0.000'), 'Peso_neto':
> Decimal('25000.000'), 'Peso_diferencia': Decimal('0.000')}, {'Numero':
> 5, 'Placa': 'A1A001P', 'Conductor': 'Juan', 'Cedula': 26725711,
> 'Producto': 'maiz', 'Numero_guia': 4, 'Peso_guia':
> Decimal('50000.000'), 'Proveedor': 'Milazo', 'Cliente': '',
> 'Despacho': '', 'Transporte': 'Balarca', 'Fecha': '30/11/2022',
> 'Hora': '12:42:26 PM', 'Observaciones': 'No', 'Peso_balanza':
> Decimal('48000.000'), 'Peso_tara': Decimal('46000.000'), 'Peso_neto':
> Decimal('2000.000'), 'Peso_diferencia': Decimal('-2000.000')}]

Comment: No logré reproducir el problema normalmente. Pero si si envío el DataFrame directamente usando el parametro data, me sucede un error similar. Si estás pasando el dataframe directamente a data, entonces te olvidaste de pasarlo a diccionario. Si no es eso, necesitaría un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para comprobar bien que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Hola DanteS. Se me había olvidado pasarlo a diccionario, pero el problema sigue ocurriendo, Puedo colocar todo el código en la pregunta, pero es bastante largo

Comment: Voy a escribirlo otra vez con lo mínimo y edito la pregunta

Comment: @DanteS. Escribí una versión mas simple y agregué la solución sugerida, pero no funcionó. Por favor cuando puedas, lee el edit y dime en donde me equivoqué

Comment: Hola Carlos, lamentablemente, sigo sin poder reproducir el error. Te puedo pedir un favor? Podrías poner, en forma de texto, algunos datos de muestra (no tienen por que ser reales, pero si parecidos) por favor? Parte de la razón por la que pedimos ejemplos minimos, completos y verificables, datos de muestra, etc, es para que la ayuda pueda darse.

Comment: Por cierto, esta linea `for column in df_sql_data['6', '14', '15', '16', '17']` debería ser `for column in ('6', '14', '15', '16', '17')` (tal como lo muestra Abulafia, ya que el itera sobre una tupla, NO sobre algo devuelto por un dataframe). Hablando de eso, probaste su propuesta de convertir los valores a cadena. Por que quizá, por tener una versión distinta de Python, parchearon el error y a mi no me sucede.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas bases de datos utilizan el tipo `decimal.Decimal` para guardar números con decimales, en lugar de usar float. Es una decisión razonable porque Decimal no tiene errores de redondeo (y por tanto es la mejor opción para tratar con dinero y sus céntimos). No obstante cuando se va a imprimir un Decimal hay que pasarlo a cadena eso puede mostrar todos los decimales almacenados, aunque todos sean cero.

Eso es lo que ves al volcarlo por la terminal. Creo que de cara a mostrarlo te vale más pasarlos todos a float, pues la representación de float como string intentará eliminar los ceros superfluos.

Para ello puedes hacer

```py
for column in ('6', '14', '15', '16', '17')
   df[column] = df[column].astype(float)
```

Esto convertirá las columnas indicadas a `float`. Y eso hará que en el `print(df)` se muestren sin tanto cero.

De todas formas, a la hora de mostrar la tabla por tk, me parece que todos los elementos de la tabla deben ser cadenas. Sospecho que sea así por el error que te ha aparecido, pues parece que ha intentado aplicar `len()` a los elementos de la tabla (esperando que todos fueran de tipo string). Si esto es así, seguirá fallando aunque los datos sean de tipo `float`.

En este caso puedes hacer `df = df.astype(str)` para convertir todas las celdas a cadena y que así funcione con Tk. Recuerda que si haces esta conversión *después* de haber hecho la anterior (a float) te evitarás todos los ceros tras la coma.

Comment: Yo pensé lo mismo, hasta que hice las pruebas y me funcionó perfecto sin convertir nada a cadena.

Comment: Hola @abulafia Creo que no entendí bien la solución, hice esto: `df_sql_data= pd.DataFrame(resultado)
    
 conn.commit()
 conn.close()
 df_sql_data.columns=[str(col) for col in df_sql_data.columns]
 for column in df_sql_data('6', '14', '15', '16', '17'):
        df_sql_data[column] = df_sql_data[column].astype(float)` Córro el ciclo for despues de crear el dataframe, pero la terminal me arroja: **   for column in df_sql_data('6', '14', '15', '16', '17'):
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a tu programa un `print(resultado)` antes de `con.commit()`? Después añade lo que te salga a la pregunta (si es demasiado largo puedes copiar ese texto a un archivo y subirlo a algún sitio para proporcionar el enlace). Es que me temo que la clave está en lo que esté retornando la base de datos.

Comment: Hola @abulafia Agregué el output que me pediste y cambié el código para copiar tu solución exactamente cómo la habías puesto. El problema es que la terminal me arroja ** KeyError: '6'** justo en la linea después del "for"